# Adding an (Int, Int) tuple to a Set in scala

Tags: scala, tuples, set

I want to add have a set of integer tuples in Scala like so:

```
var set = Set[(Int, Int)]()
```

But, when I try to add a tuple to the set by doing

```
set += (1, 2)
```

it complains

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: (Int, Int)
              set += (1, 2)
                    ^
```

But, if I do

```
set += ((1, 2))
```

it works.  Why is this the case?

Comment: In short, it's because a tuple is represented by the same symbols as an argument list, so the compiler thinks you're passing 2 Ints. You need the extra parens to resolve the ambiguity. Error message isn't that helpful, admittedly.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I needed, to both of you. @sschaef, I agree that this is a duplicate, albeit a more stripped down version of the problem.

Comment: @MatthewSaltz I agree, and prefer the answers given here.  We need a "replace old question with this one..." reverse of duplicate, don't we.